# How to limit by specific column?

Tags: sql, periscope

I am attempting to limit by top 20 states by count(to_state). However, the limit command is limiting by the service column (shipment methods). I tried googling, and the only answer I can discover is an offset command, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly. Any advice for a SQL beginner?

```
select to_state,
       count(to_state),
       service
  from uscount
group by 1, 3
order by sum(count(*)) over (partition by to_state) desc, to_state, service
limit 20
```

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sample data and expected result as numbers would help. [mcve],

Comment: Thanks, think I got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `limit` limits the number of *rows*.  But data for one state is on multiple rows.  You want 20 states, but don't know how many rows that is.

You can address this using `dense_rank()` to get the top 20 states.  Then the filtering is in the `where` clause:

```
select to_state, cnt, service
from(select ss.*,
            dense_rank() over (order by state_count desc, to_state) as seqnum
     from (select to_state, count(*) as cnt, service,
                  sum(count(*)) over (partition by to_state) as state_count
           from uscount
           group by 1, 3
          ) ss
     ) ss
where seqnum <= 20
order by state_count, to_state, service;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, great work around. That shows me a lot to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT...`

Query:

```
SELECT 
    to_state,
    count(to_state),
    service
FROM
    uscount
GROUP BY 1, 3
ORDER BY SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY to_state) DESC, to_state, service
OFFSET 0 ROW
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```